# Match any words or part of word in a field in mongodb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb

I am using MongoDB and the Mongoid ODM for MongoDB in Rails. I have a field called name and one of the document name value is " John Paul Smith". So for example:

> { "_id" : ObjectId("582bab8f9f26631b8a000088"), "name" : " JOHN PAUL
>   SMITH", "email" : "", "fax" : "", ...

I want to find this document with the keyword "John Smith". Now if I search with  " JOHN PAUL SMITH", it works:

```
Contact.where(name: " John Paul Smith").first
# => #<Contact _id: 582fab8d9f26631605000054, created_at: 2016-11-19 01:31:57 UTC, ...
```

But if I search by first and last name, it does not yield results:

```
 Contact.where(name: "John Smith").first
# => nil
```

It should produce the result even if I search by first name and just a portion of the last name, like so:

```
Contact.where(name: "John Smith").first
```

Currently, I am using the following search:

```
Contact.where({name: /.*#{condition}.*/i })
```

And it is not doing what I want, as I described above. How can I search a field by first name and last name or first name and part of last name or part of first name or first name and middle name? (I accept a solution either in MongoDB or Mongoid. I do not necessarily need a Mongoid solution. I can convert MongoDB solution into Mongoid.)

Answer (score 1):

Not a great solution but it works:

```
condition = "John Smith"
regex = '^(?=.*' + condition.split(/\s+/).map{ |x| Regexp.quote(x) }.join(')(?=.*') + ')'
@contacts = Contact.where({name: /#{regex}/i })
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use $regex from monogDB.

```
Collection.where(name: {'$regex': params[:search], '$options': 'i'})
```

it will return all the data similar to name string.